# What is the name for this form of analysis?

Tags: cryptography, data-mining, structured-data

Sorry for the vague question, but I'm trying to figure out what to call something and a more specific question title would likely require too much space. Anyway...

I'm getting into ROM hacking for fun, and I've been diving into it without any external knowledge or tools, just so I can have the pride of being able to figure it out for myself. I have a digital copy of a GameBoy Color ROM and I am analyzing its raw data to determine its structure, i.e. where the sprites, scripts, and game data are.

I enjoy this process very much, and I'd like to know what it is called. I've been calling it "data mining", but I googled it and that's more about the process of gleaning knowledge from large data sets for which the structure is known, whereas I'm trying to get raw information from a block of proprietary data with no known (by me anyway) structure. I imagine this is similar to "cryptanalysis", but that is usually referring to the process of decryption and the data I'm working with is not encrypted.

Not a huge priority, I was mainly just curious. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [reverse engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering) (and there's even [a Stack Exchange site dedicated to the topic](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/))